# Puzzled with how to efficiently form this SQL Query

Tags: java, sql, oracle

I am trying to efficiently construct a query in SQL (in a Java program) for finding 'Historical Prerequisites' for high school classes.

Basically, I have a table called PREREQUISITE that consists of tuples (`Class_name`, `Prerequisite_name`). However, a 'Historical Prerequisite' is defined as all prerequisites, and all of the prerequisite's prerequisites and so on and so forth.

At the minute I am considering creating a new table for each module, using a depth first search in Java to find previous prerequisites etc but I think it's ending up very inefficient. If anyone could offer a pointer on how to clear up my ideas I'd be very grateful.

I'm using Oracle if that is of major note.

For example, sample data:

```
Class_name              Prerequisite_name

EC104                   EC101  
EC106                   EC104  
EC210                   EC106
```

Should provide the output:

```
EC101:  
EC104: EC101  
EC106: EC101, EC104  
EC210: EC101, EC104, EC106
```

Comment: At the very least provide sample data and the desired output.

Comment: @PM77-1 Test data now supplied, sorry, oversight on my part

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To elaborate on RJD's answer, here is the way you do that in Oracle.

```
WITH -- PREREQUISITES is just test data that you should have in your table already.. you don't need this part if you have actual tables.
     prerequisites AS
       (SELECT 'EC104' class_name,
               'EC101' prerequisite_name
        FROM   DUAL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 'EC106',
               'EC104'
        FROM   DUAL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 'EC210',
               'EC106'
        FROM   DUAL),
     -- CLASSES gets a distinct list of classes, which hopefully you already have in another table.. you don't need this part if you have tables
     classes AS
       (SELECT class_name FROM prerequisites
        UNION
        SELECT prerequisite_name FROM prerequisites),
     -- HIERARCHY gets the historical dependencies -- you need this part
     hierarchy AS
       (SELECT p.*,
               CONNECT_BY_ROOT class_name AS root_class_name
        FROM   prerequisites p
        CONNECT BY class_name = PRIOR prerequisite_name)
SELECT c.class_name,
       LISTAGG (h.prerequisite_name, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY h.prerequisite_name)
FROM   classes c LEFT JOIN hierarchy h ON h.root_class_name = c.class_name
GROUP BY c.class_name
ORDER BY c.class_name
```

Comment: Hi, I'm really sorry if this sounds silly but the first block with all the `FROM DUAL UNION` etc, is this just adding the test data to the table? I have a table with real data in already, does this mean I can miss this part out?

Comment: Yes.  You wouldn't need the PREREQUISITES subfactor (i.e., `with prerequisities as...`).  But if your table isn't named "PREREQUISITES" you'll need to replace that in the `FROM` clause with the actual table name.

Comment: Also... your test data was a little simplistic.  It's possible for a single class to appear multiple times as a historical prerequisite for another class.  You didn't mention how you'd want to handle that, so I didn't include anything special in that regard.  But it's something for you to watch out for.

Answer (score 2):

without knowing specifics if is Oracle may want to look into Hierarchical Queries. "CONNECT BY" etc